# Use variables inside a completion handler somewhere else

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to convert address to coordinates in order to create a Firestorm GeoPoint object.

I currently have this code:

```
func getCoords(from address: String, locationCompletionHandler: @escaping (CLLocationCoordinate2D?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
            guard
                let placemarks = placemarks,
                let coordinate = placemarks.first?.location?.coordinate
            else {
                locationCompletionHandler(nil, error)
                return
            }
            locationCompletionHandler(coordinate, nil)
        }
}

func addressToGeoPoint(from address: String) -> GeoPoint {
    var latitude:Double = 0
    var longitude:Double = 0
    
    getCoords(from: address) { coordinate, error in
        if let coordinate = coordinate {
            latitude = coordinate.latitude
            longitude = coordinate.longitude
        }
        else {
            print("Can't get coords: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        }
    }
    
    return GeoPoint(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
}
```

The problem is that when the GeoPoint object is being initialized, the latitude and longitude variables are still 0 because the completion handler hasn't finished yet.

The function addressToGeoPoint must return a GeoPoint.
What can I do in order for this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer lies in your first method: Add another completion handler.

Comment: @vadian is on point. You should change your `func addressToGeoPoint` to incorporate a completion handler. `func addressToGeoPoint(from address: String, handler: @escaping (GeoPoint?) -> Void)`